# App crashes when using prepopulated room database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to use a prepopulated Room database but I get a crash when trying to use the database with the following error:  `java.lang.NullPointerException: cursor.getString(toColumnIndex) must not be null`

It all works fine until I add the `createFromAsset("databses/test.db")` method, when it crashes.
Nothing crashes if I just don't execute the `getAllCocktails()` method.
I already checked if the DB I inserted has all the same and I couldn't find any diferences(I also checked data gets loaded with AppInspection)

I didn't only test with `getAllCocktails()` I also tried inserting with a fully parametrized constructor

I will post (some of)my code and logs so it is easier to diagnose
I tried with Room's version 2.5.1 and 2.5.2

[test.db](https://www.mediafire.com/file/5qdgd7y17kk91bp/test.db/file#) file

Activity:

```java
public class PedirTragoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedir_trago1_1);

        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplication());

        db.cocktailDAO().getAllCocktails();
    }
}
```

RoomDatabase:

```java
@Database(entities = {
        BottleEntity.class,
        BottleIngredientEntity.class,
        CocktailEntity.class,
        CocktailIngredientEntity.class,
        IngredientTypeEntity.class
},
        version = 7)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract BottleDAO bottleDAO();

    public abstract BottleIngredientDAO bottleIngredientDAO();

    public abstract CocktailDAO cocktailDAO();

    public abstract CocktailIngredientDAO cocktailIngredientDAO();

    public abstract IngredientTypeDAO ingredientTypeDAO();
    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "barbotApp.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .createFromAsset("databases/test.db")
                    .build();

        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

BottleEntity:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "bottles")
public class BottleEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private int position;//Del 0 al 7 son alcoholes, el 8 es shaker y del 9 al 16 son mezclas
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private int capacity;
    @NonNull
    private int currentAmount;

    public BottleEntity() {
    }

    public BottleEntity(int position, String name, int capacity, int currentAmount) {
        this.position = position;
        this.name = name;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.currentAmount = currentAmount;
    }
    @Ignore
    public BottleEntity(int position, String name, int capacity) {
        this.position = position;
        this.name = name;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.currentAmount = capacity;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int getCurrentAmount() {
        return currentAmount;
    }

    public void setCurrentAmount(int currentAmount) {
        this.currentAmount = currentAmount;
    }
}
```

BottleIngredientEntity:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "bottle_ingredient",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = BottleEntity.class, parentColumns = "position", childColumns = "bottlePos"),
                @ForeignKey(entity = IngredientTypeEntity.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "ingredientId")
        })
public class BottleIngredientEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    private int id;

    @NonNull
    private int bottlePos;


    @NonNull
    private int ingredientId;


    public BottleIngredientEntity() {
    }

    public BottleIngredientEntity(int bottlePos, int ingredientId) {
        this.bottlePos = bottlePos;
        this.ingredientId = ingredientId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBottlePos() {
        return bottlePos;
    }

    public void setBottlePos(int bottlePos) {
        this.bottlePos = bottlePos;
    }

    public int getIngredientId() {
        return ingredientId;
    }

    public void setIngredientId(int ingredientId) {
        this.ingredientId = ingredientId;
    }
}
```

CocktailIngredientEntity:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "cocktail_ingredients",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = IngredientTypeEntity.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "typeId"),
                @ForeignKey(entity = CocktailEntity.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "cocktailId")
        })
public class CocktailIngredientEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    private int typeId;
    @NonNull
    private int quantity;
    @NonNull
    private int cocktailId;

    public CocktailIngredientEntity(int typeId, int quantity, int cocktailId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.cocktailId = cocktailId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    public void setTypeId(int typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getCocktailId() {
        return cocktailId;
    }

    public void setCocktailId(int cocktailId) {
        this.cocktailId = cocktailId;
    }
}
```

IngredientTypeEntity:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "ingredient_types")
public class IngredientTypeEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public IngredientTypeEntity() {
    }

    public IngredientTypeEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

CocktailEntity:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "cocktails")
public class CocktailEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @NonNull
    private boolean isOnStock;
    @NonNull
    private boolean hasIce;

    private String imgName;

    public CocktailEntity(String name, boolean isOnStock, boolean hasIce, String imgName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isOnStock = isOnStock;
        this.hasIce = hasIce;
        this.imgName = imgName;
    }

    @Ignore
    public CocktailEntity(String name, boolean hasIce, String imaName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isOnStock = false;
        this.hasIce = hasIce;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isOnStock() {
        return isOnStock;
    }

    public void setOnStock(boolean onStock) {
        isOnStock = onStock;
    }

    public boolean isHasIce() {
        return hasIce;
    }

    public void setHasIce(boolean hasIce) {
        this.hasIce = hasIce;
    }

    public String getImgName() {
        return imgName;
    }

    public void setImgName(String imgName) {
        this.imgName = imgName;
    }
}
```

CocktailDao:

```java
@Dao
public interface CocktailDAO {

    @Insert
    long insertCocktail(CocktailEntity cocktail);

    @Query("SELECT id FROM cocktails WHERE name = :name")
    int getCocktailId(String name);

    @Query("SELECT c.* FROM cocktails AS c WHERE c.id = :id")
    CocktailEntity getCocktail(int id); //Need to use a repository, separate this 2 parts

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cocktails")
    List<CocktailEntity> getAllCocktails();

    @Query("SELECT cocktails.id FROM cocktails")
    List<Integer> getAllCocktailIds();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cocktails" +
            " WHERE cocktails.isOnStock = 1")
    List<CocktailEntity> getAllCocktailsInStock();

    @Query("SELECT isOnStock FROM cocktails WHERE id = :id")
    boolean isCocktailInStock(int id);

    @Query("UPDATE cocktails SET isOnStock = :isOnStock WHERE id = :id")
    void updateCocktailStock(int id, boolean isOnStock);
}
```

Logcat:

```
2023-09-23 17:17:20.600  8250-8250  Choreographer           com.mecatronica.barbot               I  Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2023-09-23 17:17:20.801  8250-8594  AdrenoGLES-0            com.mecatronica.barbot               I  QUALCOMM build                   : 03e27f8, I326e6aff90
                                                                                                    Build Date                       : 11/02/20
                                                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.04
                                                                                                    Local Branch                     : mybrancheb1d781c-1a78-f1f4-8c78-ac1f6bcc2cee
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r116-rel
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                                                    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2023-09-23 17:17:20.801  8250-8594  AdrenoGLES-0            com.mecatronica.barbot               I  Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
2023-09-23 17:17:20.801  8250-8594  AdrenoGLES-0            com.mecatronica.barbot               I  Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2023-09-23 17:17:20.813  8250-8594  AdrenoGLES-0            com.mecatronica.barbot               I  PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
2023-09-23 17:17:21.019  8250-8594  LB                      com.mecatronica.barbot               E  fail to open file: No such file or directory
2023-09-23 17:17:21.021  8250-8594  OpenGLRenderer          com.mecatronica.barbot               I  Davey! duration=1547ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=42335033169415, Vsync=42336149836037, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=42336161943432, AnimationStart=42336162004370, PerformTraversalsStart=42336162065047, DrawStart=42336409293120, SyncQueued=42336445054213, SyncStart=42336445465515, IssueDrawCommandsStart=42336445624838, SwapBuffers=42336577074578, FrameCompleted=42336581385203, DequeueBufferDuration=272760, QueueBufferDuration=682187, GpuCompleted=1893829464, 
2023-09-23 17:17:21.027  8250-8250  Looper                  com.mecatronica.barbot               W  PerfMonitor doFrame : time=424ms vsyncFrame=0 latency=1127ms procState=2 historyMsgCount=10 (msgIndex=1 wall=1223ms seq=4 running=1128ms runnable=12ms late=2999ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159) (msgIndex=5 wall=1007ms seq=8 running=2ms runnable=1ms io=4ms late=3591ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=127)
2023-09-23 17:17:21.154  8250-8250  Looper                  com.mecatronica.barbot               W  PerfMonitor doFrame : time=35ms vsyncFrame=0 latency=459ms procState=2 historyMsgCount=4 (msgIndex=1 wall=424ms seq=14 running=255ms runnable=1ms late=1127ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver) (msgIndex=4 wall=78ms seq=17 running=70ms runnable=2ms late=413ms h=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler c=androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2)
2023-09-23 17:17:28.708  8250-8250  MiuiFrameworkFactory    com.mecatronica.barbot               V  get AllImpl object = android.common.MiuiFrameworkFactoryImpl@b038154
2023-09-23 17:17:28.726  8250-8250  MirrorManager           com.mecatronica.barbot               W  this model don't Support
2023-09-23 17:17:28.773  8250-8250  Timeline                com.mecatronica.barbot               I  Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:42344334
2023-09-23 17:17:28.996  8250-8250  DecorView[]             com.mecatronica.barbot               D  getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
2023-09-23 17:17:28.997  8250-8250  DecorView               com.mecatronica.barbot               D  createDecorCaptionView windowingMode:1 mWindowMode 1 isFullscreen: true
2023-09-23 17:17:30.631  8250-8250  AndroidRuntime          com.mecatronica.barbot               D  Shutting down VM
2023-09-23 17:17:30.646  8250-8250  AndroidRuntime          com.mecatronica.barbot               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.mecatronica.barbot, PID: 8250
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mecatronica.barbot/com.mecatronica.barbot.PedirTragoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: cursor.getString(toColumnIndex) must not be null
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3550)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3710)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2146)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: cursor.getString(toColumnIndex) must not be null
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.util.TableInfoKt.readForeignKeyFieldMappings(TableInfo.kt:536)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.util.TableInfoKt.readForeignKeys(TableInfo.kt:488)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.util.TableInfoKt.readTableInfo(TableInfo.kt:472)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.util.TableInfo$Companion.read(TableInfo.kt:130)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.util.TableInfo.read(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at com.mecatronica.barbot.database.AppDatabase_Impl$1.onValidateSchema(AppDatabase_Impl.java:136)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onCreate(RoomOpenHelper.kt:72)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onCreate(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:244)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:411)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableOrReadableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:232)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.innerGetDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:190)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:151)
                                                                                                        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:104)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.kt:71)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:638)
                                                                                                        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:457)
                                                                                                        at com.mecatronica.barbot.database.daos.CocktailDAO_Impl.getAllCocktails(CocktailDAO_Impl.java:177)
                                                                                                        at com.mecatronica.barbot.PedirTragoActivity.onCreate(PedirTragoActivity.java:63)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8157)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8129)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3523)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3710) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2146) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967) 
2023-09-23 17:17:30.716  8250-8250  Process                 com.mecatronica.barbot               I  Sending signal. PID: 8250 SIG: 9
```

sql dump form test.db:

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "ingredient_types"
(
    id   INTEGER not null
        constraint ingredient_types_pk
            primary key,
    name TEXT
);
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(1,'SHAKE');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(2,'limón');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(3,'ron');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(4,'tonica');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(5,'ginebra');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(6,'campari');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(7,'naranja');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(8,'fernet');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(9,'coca');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(10,'durazno');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(11,'granadina');
INSERT INTO ingredient_types VALUES(12,'vodka');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "bottle_ingredient"
(
    id           INTEGER not null
        constraint bottle_ingredient_pk
            primary key,
    bottlePos    INTEGER not null
        constraint bottle_ingredient_bottles_position_fk
            references bottles,
    ingredientId INTEGER not null
        constraint bottle_ingredient_ingredient_types_id_fk
            references ingredient_types
);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(1,8,5);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(2,9,6);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(3,10,8);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(4,11,3);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(5,12,12);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(7,0,2);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(8,1,4);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(9,2,7);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(10,3,9);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(11,4,10);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(12,5,11);
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient VALUES(13,16,1);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "bottles"
(
    position      INTEGER not null
        constraint bottles_pk
            primary key,
    name          TEXT,
    capacity      INTEGER not null,
    currentAmount INTEGER not null
);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(0,'limon',2000,2000);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(1,'tonica',2000,2000);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(2,'naranja',2000,2000);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(3,'coca',2000,2000);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(4,'durazno',2000,2000);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(5,'granadina',2000,2000);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(6,'Mezcla 7',1,1);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(7,'Mezcla 8',1,1);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(8,'ginebra',700,700);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(9,'campari',750,750);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(10,'fernet',750,750);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(11,'ron',750,750);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(12,'vodka',700,700);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(13,'Bottle 6',1,1);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(14,'Bottle 7',1,1);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(15,'Bottle 8',1,1);
INSERT INTO bottles VALUES(16,'Shakeo',1000,1000);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cocktail_ingredients"
(
    id         INTEGER not null
        constraint cocktail_ingredients_pk
            primary key,
    typeId     INTEGER not null
        constraint cocktail_ingredients_ingredient_types_id_fk
            references ingredient_types,
    quantity   INTEGER not null,
    cocktailId INTEGER not null
        constraint cocktail_ingredients_cocktails_id_fk
            references cocktails
);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(1,6,60,1);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(2,7,136,1);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(3,9,146,2);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(4,8,50,2);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(5,5,60,3);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(6,4,136,3);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(7,3,50,4);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(8,9,120,4);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(9,2,10,4);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(10,12,40,5);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(11,10,20,5);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(12,7,40,5);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(13,1,30,5);
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients VALUES(14,11,40,5);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cocktails"
(
    id        INTEGER not null
        constraint cocktails_pk
            primary key,
    name      TEXT,
    isOnStock INTEGER not null,
    hasIce    INTEGER not null,
    imgName   TEXT
);
INSERT INTO cocktails VALUES(1,'campari',1,1,'campari');
INSERT INTO cocktails VALUES(2,'fernet',1,1,'fernet');
INSERT INTO cocktails VALUES(3,'gin tonic',1,1,'gintonic');
INSERT INTO cocktails VALUES(4,'ron cola',1,1,'roncola');
INSERT INTO cocktails VALUES(5,'sex On  the beach',1,1,'sexOnTheBeach');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: How was `test.db` created? To help answer if might be worth dumping the database to text sql file (including schema) so you can add it to the question as there might be something in the `test.db` that does not match what the room is expecting.

Comment: It was created using Datagrip, I could try to export both DBs into sql and add it to the question

Comment: Make sure you aren't misspelling the path to the asset.  I see a typo in the line `"databAses/test.db"`, but will work only if it's also misspelled in the assets folder as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It all works fine until I add the createFromAsset("databses/test.db") method

and then from the logcat:-

> cursor.getString(toColumnIndex) must not be null

Is probably due to the data from the asset having nulls (or at least one null) in a column when the column in the `@Entity` annotated class does not allow nulls.

It should also be noted that if you exclude `db.cocktailDAO().getAllCocktails();` then the database will not even be accessed and thus not even created. That is just getting an instance of the database does not open the database, the open is delayed until an attempt is made to access the database.

**Summary of findings**

The issue, is as predicted, the asset. However it has nothing to do with the getAllCocktails method other than this is what causes the database to be opened and thus the copy of the asset then the opeing of the database.

In this case, as the asset is first copied to a temporary database and then to the actual Room database, the exception was (it is believed) the copy from the asset to the actual database where the exception occurred.

The actual issue being due to discrepancies between the database schema expected (actually required) by Room and the schema of the asset.

As is always suggested, rather than trying to predict Room VERY STRICT schema requirements, the schema that is available in the generated after successfully compiling the project, should be used.

**See fix below for how this specific issue can be resolved.**

It won't appear to be an issue until you actually try to retrieve the data and hence why the issue only appears when you introduce the data from the asset.

You have two options:-

1. modify the `@Entity` annotated class to allow nulls for the column(s), or
2. modify the source data to not have nulls.

You may wish to modify your question to include:-

1. The `@Entity` annotated class or classes.
2. The `@Dao` annotated class.

**Working example showing the issue is very likely with the asset**

Created AS project using your code (other than using MainActivity instead of PedirTragoActivity) and altered MainActivity to be:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppDatabase db;
    String TAG = "DBINFO";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplication());
        logAllCocktails(db.cocktailDAO().getAllCocktails(),"STG01");
        db.cocktailDAO().insertCocktail(new CocktailEntity("C1",false,"Blah1"));
        db.cocktailDAO().insertCocktail(new CocktailEntity("C2",true,"Blah2"));
        db.cocktailDAO().insertCocktail(new CocktailEntity("C3",false,"Blah3"));
        logAllCocktails(db.cocktailDAO().getAllCocktails(),"STG02");
        db.close();
    }

    void logAllCocktails(List<CocktailEntity> allCocktails,String tag_suffix) {
        Log.d(TAG +tag_suffix,"Starting Log of All Cocktails where supplied list has " + allCocktails.size() + " items.");
        for (CocktailEntity ce: allCocktails) {
            Log.d(
                    TAG+tag_suffix,
                    "Cocktail Name is " + ce.getName() + " HasIce is " + ce.isHasIce() + " ID is " + ce.getId() + " ImageName is " + ce.getImgName()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Ran the above twice with createFromAsset commented out. Log showed first 0 Cocktails, the after the 3 inserts 3 Cocktails. Second run showed 3 and 6.

Note the addition of the close (this to force the WAL to be committed so just one file).

Used Device Explorer to copy the database file into the assets folder and then into the assets/database folder as test.db e.g. :-

[image]

Uninstalled the App included the createFromAsset code and reran:-

Resultant Log:-

```
2023-09-24 07:51:34.929 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG01: Starting Log of All Cocktails where supplied list has 6 items.
2023-09-24 07:51:34.929 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is C1 HasIce is false ID is 1 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.929 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is C2 HasIce is true ID is 2 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.929 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is C3 HasIce is false ID is 3 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.929 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is C1 HasIce is false ID is 4 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.929 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is C2 HasIce is true ID is 5 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.929 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is C3 HasIce is false ID is 6 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Starting Log of All Cocktails where supplied list has 9 items.
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C1 HasIce is false ID is 1 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C2 HasIce is true ID is 2 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C3 HasIce is false ID is 3 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C1 HasIce is false ID is 4 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C2 HasIce is true ID is 5 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C3 HasIce is false ID is 6 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C1 HasIce is false ID is 7 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C2 HasIce is true ID is 8 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 07:51:34.953 21370-21370/a.a.so77164866javaroomnpefromasset D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C3 HasIce is false ID is 9 ImageName is null
```

- i.e. NO NPE Crash
- Originally the 6 rows from the previous runs, then
- 9 rows after 3 new rows inserted.
- Note the constrcutor `public CocktailEntity(String name, boolean hasIce, String imaName)` was used, hence the nulls for imageName (and that these being null are not an issue)

**Edit using downloaded mediafile test.db**

In short this is fine and works (at both Version 1 and Version 7).

As such the issue does not appear to be with the supplied code (database wise) nor with the file itself.

i.e. at Version 7, for a fresh install then the log (as per the code above) results in :-

```
2023-09-24 12:01:19.596 D/DBINFOSTG01: Starting Log of All Cocktails where supplied list has 5 items.
2023-09-24 12:01:19.596 D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is campari HasIce is true ID is 1 ImageName is campari
2023-09-24 12:01:19.596 D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is fernet HasIce is true ID is 2 ImageName is fernet
2023-09-24 12:01:19.596 D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is gin tonic HasIce is true ID is 3 ImageName is gintonic
2023-09-24 12:01:19.596 D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is ron cola HasIce is true ID is 4 ImageName is roncola
2023-09-24 12:01:19.596 D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is sex On  the beach HasIce is true ID is 5 ImageName is sexOnTheBeach
2023-09-24 12:01:19.608 D/DBINFOSTG02: Starting Log of All Cocktails where supplied list has 8 items.
2023-09-24 12:01:19.608 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is campari HasIce is true ID is 1 ImageName is campari
2023-09-24 12:01:19.608 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is fernet HasIce is true ID is 2 ImageName is fernet
2023-09-24 12:01:19.608 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is gin tonic HasIce is true ID is 3 ImageName is gintonic
2023-09-24 12:01:19.608 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is ron cola HasIce is true ID is 4 ImageName is roncola
2023-09-24 12:01:19.609 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is sex On  the beach HasIce is true ID is 5 ImageName is sexOnTheBeach
2023-09-24 12:01:19.609 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C1 HasIce is false ID is 6 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 12:01:19.609 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C2 HasIce is true ID is 7 ImageName is null
2023-09-24 12:01:19.609 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is C3 HasIce is false ID is 8 ImageName is null
```

Therefore the issue is perhaps likely to the differences between the two Apps, which could be many.

- The device (works on AS emulator for 10.1 device API 28)
- The Activity (very simple initial Activity without anything special layout wise) i.e. the layouts for the Activity are different.
- You have Entities commented out in the posted code **BUT** do you have the other entities excluded when testing/running? if not then the log indicates **Foreign Key** activity. So it may be that the issue is due to NULL being an invalid Foreign Key.

  - error is immediately after `at androidx.room.util.TableInfoKt.readForeignKeyFieldMappings(TableInfo.kt:536)`
  - **kt** perhaps indicates Kotlin code, for a java App????

**Edit Adding additional Entities**

- Add BottleEntity, no issues after run.
- Add BottleIngredientEntity, requires IngredientTypeEntity.
- Add IngredientTypeEntity **NPE cursor.getString(toColumnIndex) must not be null**

**So issue is with IngredientTypeEntity/BottleIngredientEnitity**

- commented out FKEY definitions, **issue remains**.
- commented out IngredientTYpeEntity, **issue remains**.
- commented out BottleIngredientEntity, re-introduced IngredientTypeEntity, no issues after run.

As such issue very much appears to be with **BottleIngredientEntity**.

```
- note uninstalling App prior to each run.
```

**At this stage comment out createFromAsset to see if issue is with schema rather than data**

- include `db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();` to force open of the database.
- exclude inserts and logging as probably not an issue.
- run App, no issue.
- reintroduce BottleIngredientEntity and run App, not an issue.
- reintroduce FKEY definitions for BottleIngredientEntity and run App, not an issue.

So the issue very much appears to be the BottleIngredientEntity and how Room manages handling the asset. iirc that a temp db is used which is then copied.

- Compare schemas BottleIngredient table:-

Asset is:-

```
CREATE TABLE "bottle_ingredient"
(
    id           INTEGER not null
        constraint bottle_ingredient_pk
            primary key,
    bottlePos    INTEGER not null
        constraint bottle_ingredient_bottles_position_fk
            references bottles,
    ingredientId INTEGER not null
        constraint bottle_ingredient_ingredient_types_id_fk
            references ingredient_types
)
```

Room is :-

```
CREATE TABLE `bottle_ingredient` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    `bottlePos` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `ingredientId` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY(`bottlePos`) REFERENCES `bottles`(`position`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION , 
    FOREIGN KEY(`ingredientId`) REFERENCES `ingredient_types`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION 
)
```

- I suspect that even without the NPE issue that an Expected but Found exception would eventuate.

---

**Advised fix**

---

My suggestion is to drop using the asset you currently have and use a Tool (know nothing about Datagrip) where YOU create the schema in accordance with Room and populate the data accordingly.

That is:-

1. compile the project then inspect the `java(generated)` (visible from Android Studio's **Android View**)
2. locate the AppDatabase_Impl class.
3. find the **createAllTables** method in the class and copy the SQL for creating the tables (no need to create `room_master_table` or insert into it).
4. change the database version, via the tool or SQL to version 7
5. populate the tables as required.
6. save the database ensuring that there is a single file (i.e. no -wal or -shm file) (e.g. with Navicat you have to close navicat for it to fully commit).
7. then copy this file into the asset.

**note DO NOT turn Foreign Keys off**, I suspect that the column cannot be null is due to an invalid reference in the data that you load and that this exception occurs as part of the copying of the asset from the temp to actual db.

example of getting the CREATE SQL :-

[image]

---

---

### **FINAL FIX**

---

As per the above, I believe the core issue is that the SCHEMA of your  asset database does not match what Room expects **BUT** this is masked due to an exception as part of the asset copy when copying the  asset to the final Room database from the temporary initial copy.

So the fix is to use the expected schema, the SQL for which is available in the generate java in the `createAllTables` method of the  AppDatabase_Impl class (i.e. the `@Database` annotated class suffixed with _Impl).

To utilise the existing data in the asset, then a conversion can be run. This will rename the existing tables, create the new tables as per the generated SQL and then load the data from the renamed tables. Additionally it will set the user_version (the database version) to 7 (to ensure that fallback doesn't clear the database as there appears to no Migrations, so a version less than 7 would then expect a Migration but in the absence clear the database).

The SQL script being:-

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_user_version;
/* RUN ALTERS ONCE ONLY ELSE WILL FAIL OR COPY POTENTIALLY NOT ORIGINAL DATA */
/* COMMENTED OUT AS ALREADY DO ONCE */
/*
ALTER TABLE bottles RENAME TO bottles_old;
ALTER TABLE bottle_ingredient RENAME TO bottle_ingredient_old;
ALTER TABLE cocktail_ingredients RENAME TO cocktail_ingredients_old;
ALTER TABLE cocktails RENAME TO cocktails_old;
ALTER TABLE ingredient_types RENAME TO ingredient_types_old;
*/
 /* Optional DROPS but ensures tables are recreated */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cocktail_ingredients`; /* best to drop tables with FKEYS first */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bottle_ingredient`; /* best to drop tables with FKEYS first */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cocktails`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bottles`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingredient_types;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cocktails` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    `name` TEXT, `isOnStock` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `hasIce` INTEGER NOT NULL, `imgName` TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bottles` (
    `position` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` TEXT, 
    `capacity` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `currentAmount` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(`position`)
);
/* NOTE MOVED TO BEFORE bottle_ingredients */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ingredient_types` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    `name` TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bottle_ingredient` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    `bottlePos` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `ingredientId` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY(`bottlePos`) REFERENCES `bottles`(`position`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION , 
    FOREIGN KEY(`ingredientId`) REFERENCES `ingredient_types`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cocktail_ingredients` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    `typeId` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `quantity` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `cocktailId` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY(`typeId`) REFERENCES `ingredient_types`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION , 
    FOREIGN KEY(`cocktailId`) REFERENCES `cocktails`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION 
);
INSERT INTO cocktails SELECT * FROM cocktails_old;
INSERT INTO bottles SELECT * FROM bottles_old;
INSERT INTO ingredient_types SELECT * FROM ingredient_types_old;
INSERT INTO bottle_ingredient SELECT * FROM bottle_ingredient_old;
INSERT INTO cocktail_ingredients SELECT * FROM cocktail_ingredients_old;
PRAGMA user_version = 7;
SELECT * FROM pragma_user_version;
```

- Note that Navicat was used, Navicat allows multiple statements to be executed and also multiple outputs.
- Please read comments **ESPECIALLY** that the **ALL important ALTER statements have been commented out**.

Once converted (and checked for the correct/expected data) then save the database file, ensuring that there is no -wal or -shm file (with Navicat you have to close/end Navicat for it to close the file). Then copy the file into the asset and all should be fine.

- Note you may wish to drop the ????_old tables (but Room will not care that they exist, but they will waste space (minimum 4k per compnent (table index ....))).

After following the above, uninstalling the App and running then the log (inserts commented out):-

```
2023-09-24 14:01:14.970 D/DBINFOSTG02: Starting Log of All Cocktails where supplied list has 5 items.
2023-09-24 14:01:14.970 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is campari HasIce is true ID is 1 ImageName is campari
2023-09-24 14:01:14.970 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is fernet HasIce is true ID is 2 ImageName is fernet
2023-09-24 14:01:14.970 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is gin tonic HasIce is true ID is 3 ImageName is gintonic
2023-09-24 14:01:14.970 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is ron cola HasIce is true ID is 4 ImageName is roncola
2023-09-24 14:01:14.970 D/DBINFOSTG02: Cocktail Name is sex On  the beach HasIce is true ID is 5 ImageName is sexOnTheBeach
```

Using App Inspection (to run a query) shows:-

[image]

Comment: Sadly that's not the issue since i don't have any null value. Will post entieies and daos if they are useful

Comment: @MatiasChiaia Pretty sure that it is your data in the asset that is the issue. Will update answer with evidence.

Comment: @MatiasChiaia you may wish to provide a link to the actual test.db file that you are using, this could then be tested.

Comment: It probably is something related to the test.db I made, but I don't have any null value, what else could it be?

Comment: Sure, are you OK  with mediafire link with test.db? You would also need to modify the other tables I didn't mention. (or delete them from test.db) Here is mediafire link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/8t4002jzwzsr7g0/test.db/file

Comment: @Mathias Uhhm could be that you have omitted the -wal file (note how I closed the db to force commit of the -wal file)

Comment: @Mathias as other tables are not in the list of Entities then Room will not expect them so they are ignored. I'm actually off out shortly but provide a link and I will see (never used mediafire but would see if I could when I get back).

Comment: Btw tested also inserting data with a parametrized constructor and it didn't work in my case

Comment: Just added Sql dump in my post if you don't want to download the .db file

Comment: @MatiasChiaia Dumped data works e.g. `D/DBINFOSTG01: Cocktail Name is campari HasIce is true ID is 1 ImageName is campari` (used your SQL in Navicat). However had to revert to version 1 (else Migrations run and as none then fallbackToDestructive). But cannot reproduce. Suspect WAL file missing. link the actual file as that is very likely where the problem lies.

Comment: @MatiasChiaia try using https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hTtP_tuOoWtNDCiOOcgo66F1kOxQc3o/view?usp=sharing (but to use change database version to 1).

Comment: I added the test.db in the original post and also the entities I didn't post before

Comment: Could you make that google drive file public so I can download it?

Comment: If my issue is the WAL file is missing then how do I add it? Doesn't it get created along room DB?

Comment: @MatiasChiaia edited the answer, in short redo the asset as advised (time permitting may show this works).

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow I will this. But i DID create the test.db manually, Datagrip is just a databse IDE

Comment: @MatiasChiaia **BUT** it will not be as Room expects. possibly can use DataGrip. (currently looking at doing a conversion via SQL).

Comment: Didn't think on looking up the statements that Room used to create te DB, will do it and test with it. I also never changed database version to version 7 on test.db, I will test with just that as a change (Just tested it, didn't work, will test tomorrow with all the changes)

Comment: OK have just got it working, Will be updating answer accordingly with a conversion Script (BUT leaves in old tables just in case). Might be able to run SQL script via DataGrip.

Comment: @MatiasChiaia answer now complete (with results of a successful conversion of your data and not one edit of the actual data).

Comment: @MatiasChiaia ooops didn;t see make download public, think I've done so now. Not that it matters.